# Need href div name on www link

Tags: jquery, http, html, navigation, href

I need my link to look like www.name.com/#/welcome, and welcome to be a div from the same page. I made a jquery that looks like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.Tab = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(".menu-nav li").click(function() {

    $("#container").fadeIn('fast');
            $(".menu-nav li").removeClass('current');
    $('#home').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass("current");
            $(".tab_content").hide();
            var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    var name_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("alt");
            $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
    $(document).attr('title', 'My Title | ' + name_tab);
            return false;
        });
        $('#home').addClass('current');
    $("#container").fadeOut('fast');
    $(".menu-nav li").removeClass('current');

    });
};
        $(function() {
            $(".menu-nav").Tab();
        });
})(jQuery);
```

I really don't want to change this code. Also, if someone navigate to my link that looks like www.name.com/#/welcome , I want to open that 'id="welcome"' div!

Comment: do you mean `www.name.com/#welcome`, without the last `/`?

Comment: I want it with the last /, www.name.com/#/example. It's possible ?

Comment: But without the last /, how it will be ?